# c# How to use string.Split() with multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, string, split

I need to split a string after the `&` sign and after two newlines (`\r\n\r\n`).

The `string.Split()` method doesn't accept this high number of parameters. How to split the string into an array using the needed parameters in the easiest way?

My try of use `string.Split()`:

```
string[] sort = result.Split('&\r\n\r\n');
```

Comment: You are trying to use char identifier ' you need to use the string identifier "

Comment: @deathismyfriend: You are right, but it is a little hard to find. Not very straight forward if you ask me.

Answer (score 5):

You should pass it as a `string[]` using [this overload of `Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] sort = result.Split(new string[] { "&\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

In fact there is no need for the `string[]`, beside that the signature of the method demands it. There is no overload with just `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Regex` to split. Like this.

`string[] sort = Regex.Split(result,"&\r\n\r\n");`

Use have to use this `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to use above.

Comment: Although this is a good solution, be aware of the overhead of regex compared to a regular `string.Split`.

Comment: I have the use of a Regex in mind, but for this project I don't want to include another using, I think .split() should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code above using .split() for the text(just a part of the whole):

```
 value = 15

 test123=xxx
```

As you may see, there are two newlines between the '15' and the beginning of 'test'. I tried to use this code to split:

```
 string[] sort = result.Split(new string[] {"\n\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

After trying to print the value of sort[1] which should be 'test123=xxx' the IDE told me the field [1] of array sort wasn't found, I tried to use the code above, by using one '\n' all works fine, but using two newline commands .split() doesn't work. How to fix?